# Alaska Series E projection in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, united-states

I am trying to digitize a scanned map that appears to be in the Alaska Series E projection. I have also seen this referred to as Modified Transverse Mercator. While this projection is listed as supported by ArcGIS, I can't seem to find it when changing the coordinate system in Data Frame properties. Has anyone worked with the Alaska Series E projection and how do you get it to project properly in ArcMap? I am running ArcGIS 10.3 and I have an Advanced license.

ArcGIS entry for Alaska Series E:
http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Alaska_Series_E/003r0000001m000000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

Alaska E has two differing definitions if I remember correctly. You need the post-1973 definition I assume. Pre-1973 data may be on a different system although named the same (Alska Series E is the common name).

This [link](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1991/0553a/report.pdf) gives you some of the information you need to define the projection. Page 73 strangely enough. As I say, the meridians switched in ~73 so be careful.

From the ESRI help, I can see it is not predefined in Arc 10.3.

Page [64](https://books.google.com/books?id=nPdOAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=alaska%20projection%20MAP%20e%20usgs%20parameters&source=bl&ots=f4usgoVmgS&sig=1tytdXvnyz2PPzNRAP2dp5K5qPY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqtKa7k9zJAhUBVGMKHQfQDSQQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=alaska&f=false) of this book appears to have the information you need to define it. I could not find it on spatial reference either.

EDIT - [Here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8447/) is the information at spatial reference as uploaded as a result of this exchange.

Comment: Do us a favor. If you have made a .prj and it works post it in spatial reference for others to use in the future. Then we can just point them to it if it comes up no the board again.

Comment: not entirely sure that I did this correctly. Here it is: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8447/